# generate combinations of elements

Tags: r, combinations, element

I have a vector of elements of `1:3`

I want to generate the possible combinations of these elements so that I only have `1-2`, `1-3` and `2-3`.

I've tried with `expand.grid` but get ALL possible ones when this is not what I want. How do I get the main three easily?

```
expand.grid(1:3,1:3)
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3
8    2    3
9    3    3
```

Comment: **`combn(1:3,2)`**

Comment: Brilliant! And how would I get the result of that as `1-2`, `1-3`, `2-3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
combn(x = 1:3, m = 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "-")
#[1] "1-2" "1-3" "2-3"

#OR

apply(X = combn(1:3,2), MARGIN = 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "-")
#[1] "1-2" "1-3" "2-3"
```