# generate combinations of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have 9 arrays that I want to manipulate to find all possible combinations, so that the name of the resulting array tells me which arrays have been combined. For example:

```
a1_a2 = array1 - array2
a1_a3 = array1 - array3
a1_a4 = array1 - array4
.
.
.
a9_a6 = array9 - array6
a9_a7 = array9 - array7
a9_a8 = array9 - array8
```

Obviously I could hardcode it, but how could I do it in a loop?

I thought of writing a function for it, something like:

```
def combineArrays(array1, array2):
    result_name = name_of_array1 + '_' + name_of_array2 # How would I do this bit?
    result = array1 - array2
    return result

for firstArray in arrays:
    for secondArray in reversed(arrays): # to go backwards through the list of arrays
        combineArrays(firstArray, secondArray)
```

As an example, the following arrays:

```
array1 = [1,2,nan,4,5]
array2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
array3 = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

should produce the output

```
a1_a2 = [-4,-2,nan,2,4]
a1_a3 = [-2,-4,nan,-8,-10]
a2_a1 = [4,2,nan,-2,-4]
a2_a3 = [2,-2,-6,-10,-14]
a3_a2 = [-2,2,6,10,14]
a3_a1 = [2,4,nan,8,10]
```

so, element-wise subtraction for each possible combination of arrays.

Since I'm using `numpy`, is there even a linear algebra-type way to do this? And how can I get the program to name the arrays for me?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443196/generate-combinations-of-elements) seems to be asking something similar, but I don't understand the answer.

Comment: You are manipulating the array while the outer for-loop is iterating over it. Also, `.reverse()` doesn't return the array, meaning the inner for-loop should probably fail. You'd probably want to use `reversed(arrays)` or `arrays[::-1]` if you'd like to get a copy of a reversed list.

Comment: I just want to iterate backwards through the list of arrays. I guess arrays[::-1] would work better. I'll update.

Comment: What do you mean `name_of_array1` ? What would you like to do when you say `array1 - array2` -- element wise subtraction? Can you update your post with a stripped down sample input and sample output?

Comment: 1_2 etc are not valid python identifiers. You simply can't name variables that

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, you're quite right; those are just identifiers I put in as examples. I'll update my question.

Comment: It's a very rookie thing to want a separate named variable for everything. It's much better to decide on the appropriate data structure to manage your data. A dict or even 3D matrix would be nice here. I'd be happy to post either in an answer if you're not dead set on named variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generalized code that works with any function: You might go through it to understand but it does what you exactly want:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)



def choose(n,m):
    if n < m:
        raise ValueError("n is less than m!")
    if m < 0:
        raise ValueError("m cannot be negative!!")
    else:
        return int(factorial(n)/factorial(m)/factorial(n-m))


def combn(x, m, FUN = None):
    import numpy as np
    if not isinstance(m,int):
        raise ValueError("m must be a single integer")

    if isinstance(x, int)  and x > 0:
      x = np.arange(1, x+1)

    n, x, e, h, a, nofun = len(x), np.array(x), 0, m, np.arange(1,m+1), FUN==None

    if not nofun and not callable(FUN):
        raise TypeError("'FUN' must be a function or None")

    if (nofun):r = x[a-1] 
    else: r = FUN(x[a-1])   
    out = [None] * choose(n, m)
    out[0] = r

    if m > 0:  
        i = 2
        nmmp1 = n - m + 1
        while a[0] != nmmp1:
          if e < n - h:
            h, e, j = 1, a[m-1], 1
          else:
            e = a[m - h-1]
            h += 1
            j = np.arange(1,h+1)

          a[m - h + j-1] = e + j
          if (nofun): r = x[a-1]
          else: r = FUN(x[a-1])
          out[i-1] = r
          i += 1
    return out
```

You can save this for future use:. Now after this you can do any combinations that you want:

```
 combn(4,3)
Out[854]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 4]), array([1, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4])]

combn([1,2,3,4],3)
Out[855]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 4]), array([1, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4])]

 combn([1,2,3,4],3,sum)
Out[856]: [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In your case, you could do:

```
array1 = [1,2,np.nan,4,5]
array2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
array3 = [2,4,6,8,10]

combn([array1,array2,array3],2,lambda x: x[0]-x[1])
Out[859]: 
[array([-4., -2., nan,  2.,  4.]),
 array([-1., -2., nan, -4., -5.]),
 array([ 3.,  0., -3., -6., -9.])]
```

Now run the same code with `lambda x:x[1]-x[0]` thus giving you all the combinations that you want