# List gets mutated but i didnt mutate it directly

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables, dplyr

In my code I try to get every combination of elements in a list (I didn't want to use itertools). I do that by counting in binary with `True` and `False` and later I apply that on the original list to get all combinations (If It's True the number will stay in the list of not it will get removed). Now I assigned `x` with 0  so `[False, False, ...]` and in the loop, the binary numbers get added. Now the problem is that if I want to reset the list to be 0 it will not change and just continue to use the previous list. e.g In the first code where it `print(x)` it prints: `[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,],[True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,],[True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,], ...]`. I can print either `x` or `test` and it will print the same result but I didn't changed x. Any ideas?

```
def get_combinations(arr):
    true = []
    x = []

    for thing in range(0,len(arr)):
        true.append(thing)
        x.append(False)

    true.sort(reverse=True)
    test = []
    final = []
    länge = 2**len(arr)
    for number in range(länge):

        test = x   <------------------------------- here
        #print(x) or print(test)
        for thing in true:

            if number / (2**thing) >= 1:
                test[thing] = True
                number -= 2**thing  
  
        final.append(test)

    return final


test = [1,2,4,5,3,1,5,13]
get_combinations(test)
```

If I change the line to :

```
test = [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

it works fine.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529995/generate-combinations-of-arrays/51531218#51531218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup "Deep Copy v/s Shallow copy in Python"

In short :

```
x= [1,2,3]
```

If:

```
y = x       # x: [1,2,3]  , y: [1,2,3]
y[0] = 4    # x: [4,2,3]  , y: [4,2,3]
```

-- note that by `y = x` both 'y' and 'x' are set equal but more importantly 'x' and 'y' are the same object ... any change in one will change the other.
Therefore `y[0] = 4` also affects x. i.e. `x[0] is also now 4`.

On the other hand :

```
y = x.copy()  # x: [1,2,3]  , y: [1,2,3]
y[0] = 4      # x: [1,2,3]  , y: [4,2,3]
```

-- here 'y' has the same value as 'x' but they are different objects.
changing y via `y[0] = 4` doesnt affect 'x'.

In your code :

```
test =x
```

and later elements of 'test' are modified , changing 'x',
then in the next iteration of the `for loop`, 'x'is no longer [False,False...]

Replace that line with:

```
test =x.copy()
```